# Why is $\mathbb{E}[(\bar{X})^{2}] \not = \mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$ in an iid distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

My work that is probably wrong somehow:

$\mathbb{E}[(\bar{X})^{2}] = \mathbb{E}[(\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_{i}}{n})^{2}]$

$ = \frac{1}{n^{2}} \mathbb{E}[(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_{i})^{2}]$

$ = \frac{1}{n^{2}} \mathbb{E}[\underbrace{X^{2} + X^{2} \cdots}_{n^{2}\text{ times}}]$

$ = \mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$

Comment: $(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2\neq a^2+b^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you square $X_1+\cdots +X_n$, and take the expectation, you get **two types** of term, $E(X_i^2)$ and $E(X_iX_j)$, with $i\ne j$. These expectations are in general different.

By independence, we have $E(X_iX_j)=E(X_i)E(X_j)=(E(X_i))^2$. This is in general (indeed almost always) different from $E(X_i^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

When expanding out the square of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, you also get "cross-terms" $2 X_i X_j$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to remember the difference. Look at any distribution symmetric around zero and not constant (normal distribution). Then we have that $\bar{X} = 0$, but since $X^2$ is always positive, $E[X^2]>0$. So they can't be the same.